# C/C++ XML Library that presents read files as a simple data structure?

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

Is there a library that focuses on reading XML data and presenting it to the programmer as an easily navigated structure, like a tree?  The simpler the structure, the better.  Features like validation, speed, etc are not needed.

I want to extract data from a .dae file (a 3D object format using XML) produced by Blender, such that I can cherry pick out information I need, (vertices, normals, armatures, etc) and write it out to a more specific format that's easier to parse for my final, separate OpenGL program later.

Comment: Any DOM parser will do. It parses the XML stream into a tree of XML nodes.

Comment: @IInspectable - Thanks.  Searching around a bit harder, I came across TinyXML, which seems to be just what I needed

Comment: And __that's__ how a question is answered.  +1 Hooray!